# How to do algebra on unevaluated integrals?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, algebraic-manipulation

I am working with functions calculated from a set of general basis functions.

```
f = a[x] + c1*b[x] + c2*c[x];
g = Expand[f*f];
h = Integrate[g, {x, -Infinity, Infinity}];
```

This much works fine, and I get a nice expression with products of combinations of `a[x]`, `b[x]`, and `c[x]` in the integrand.  But now I need to calculate the values of `c1` and `c2` that optimize `h` and the optimal value of `h`.  This fails:

```
cs = {c1, c2};
s = Solve[{D[h, #] & /@ cs == 0}, cs]
(* Solve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve. >> *)
```

Is there any hack to make this work?

EVEN better would be if I could get the answer in tidy bracket notation, where for example  denotes the definite integral of `a[x]*b[x]`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Similar idea to belisarius, except in V10 we can inactivate `Integrate` to keep it from evaluating or even trying to evaluate:

```
h = Inactive[Integrate][g, {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

It is not necessary in this example, as belisarius' answer shows, but one of its intended uses is to do algebra/calculus on integrals and derivatives.  `Inactive` can be removed easily with

```
Activate[h]
```

The function `linearExpand` expands its argument according to linearity properties.  Factors/terms that do not depend on `x` are treated as constants (see update below for a more general approach).

```
Clear[linearExpand];
linearExpand[e_] := e //. {int : Inactive[Integrate][_Plus, _] :> Distribute[int], 
    Inactive[Integrate][integrand_Times, dom : {x_, _, _} | x_] :> 
     With[{dependencies = Internal`DependsOnQ[#, x] & /@ List @@ integrand},
      Pick[integrand, dependencies, False] *
       Inactive[Integrate][Pick[integrand, dependencies, True], dom]
      ]};
```

OP's sample problem:

```
Solve[D[h, #] == 0 & /@ cs // linearExpand, cs]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
D[h, #] == 0 & /@ cs // linearExpand
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

**For what it's worth...**

...here's a general linearity expander.  Considers factors that do not depend on `x`, which may be a list of symbols, as constants.

```
linearExpand[e_, x_, head_] := 
  e //. {op : head[arg_Plus, __] :> Distribute[op], 
    head[arg1_Times, rest__] :> 
     With[{dependencies = Internal`DependsOnQ[#, x] & /@ List @@ arg1},
      Pick[arg1, dependencies, False] head[
        Pick[arg1, dependencies, True], rest]
      ]};
```

Examples:

```
linearExpand[D[h, #] == 0 & /@ cs, x, Inactive[Integrate]]
(* same as above *)

linearExpand[foo[(a[x] + c b[y]) (2 a[x] - c b[y]) // Expand, randomarg], x, foo]
(*  -c^2 b[y]^2 foo[1, randomarg] +
     c b[y] foo[a[x], randomarg] + 
     2 foo[a[x]^2, randomarg]        *)

linearExpand[foo[(a[x] + c b[y]) (2 a[x] - c b[y]) // Expand, randomarg], {x, y}, foo]
(*  2 foo[a[x]^2, randomarg] +
    c foo[a[x] b[y], randomarg] - 
    c^2 foo[b[y]^2, randomarg]     *)
```

Answer (score 13):

```
f = a[x] + c1*b[x] + c2*c[x];
g = Expand[f*f];

(* we need to get the constants out of the integrals first*)

h = Distribute@Integrate[g, {x, -∞, ∞}] //. Integrate[q1___  r__  q2___, {v_, s__}] /; 
                                        FreeQ[{r}, v] :> r Integrate[q1 q2, {v, s}];

s= Solve[And @@ Thread[D[h, #] & /@ {c1, c2} == 0], {c1, c2}]

(* now we go to bra-ket notation *)

bkRulez = {Integrate[a_ [x] b_[x], {x, -∞, ∞}]     ->   AngleBracket[a, b], 
           Integrate[Power[a_ [x], 2], {x, -∞, ∞}] ->   AngleBracket[a, a]}
Column @@ (s /. bkRulez) // TeXForm
```

$$\begin{array}{l}
 \text{c1}\to -\frac{\langle a,c\rangle 
   \langle b,c\rangle -\langle
   c,c\rangle  \langle a,b\rangle
   }{\langle b,c\rangle ^2-\langle
   b,b\rangle  \langle c,c\rangle } \\
 \text{c2}\to -\frac{\langle b,b\rangle 
   \langle a,c\rangle -\langle
   a,b\rangle  \langle b,c\rangle
   }{\langle b,b\rangle  \langle
   c,c\rangle -\langle b,c\rangle ^2} \\
\end{array}$$

Comment: Cool, thanks!  Can you tell me how you got the ouput to format that way on mathematica.SE?  When I try to cut-paste output, it comes out as hard-to-read flat text, not formatted like in my mathematica window.  The editing-help page strangely does not cover this topic.

Comment: @JerryGuern Try enclosing the `TeXForm` in **\$ ... \$** or in **\$\$ ... \$\$**

Comment: @JerryGuern Check this http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: All that did was put the text in a different font.  But it's still writing out "Integral" etc instead of putting a nice integral symbol like in the text I copied.

Comment: @JerryGuern But you need to put the `TeXForm[ expr ]` inside the `$ ... $` !

Comment: @JerryGuern See the source of my post here http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/revisions/a6368cdf-7c39-4b1b-9273-94ce840f2d3f/view-source

Comment: Thanks for all the help!  But I have a minor coding question, because I am new to Mathematica.  Why did you do this: 
    Solve[And @@ Thread[D[h, #] & /@ {c1, c2} == 0], {c1, c2}]  
instead of this?:
    Solve[{D[h, #] & /@ {c1, c2} == 0}, {c1, c2}]
Do the And and Thread buy something?

Comment: @JerryGuern The form I used here is useful in more general situations where you have AND/OR clauses. For this particular problem your way is enough

Answer (score 1):

I played with the commands suggested above and found that Distributed[] solved the first half of the problem but only for indefinite integrals:

```
f = a[x] + c1*b[x] + c2*c[x];
g = Expand[f*f];
h = Distribute[Integrate[g, x]];
cs = {c1, c2};
Solve[{D[h, #] & /@ cs == 0}, cs]
```

I worry when my solution looks too simple...  Are the more complicated answers above handling some problem I'm not aware of?

Comment: Your solution doesn't seem to work with your original equation `Solve[{D[h, #] & /@ {c1, c2} == 0}, {c1, c2}]`, which is necessary if you plan to have more cis...

Comment: @belisarius Why did you say it doesn't work?  It worked fine for me.  But I edited the code above so the Solve line can handle a long cs list.

Comment: Well ... it didn't work for me yesterday :( Or so I believe

Comment: @JerryGuern Neat.  I'm sure I tried that and the constants did not come out of the integrals (for `h`).  Then `Solve` wouldn't work.

Comment: @belisarius It's an odd/even bug.  Works on even-numbered days.

Comment: @MichaelE2 No, I got it. Now Jerry is working with indefinite integrals and it works. Not for definite integrals, though

Comment: @belisarius  Dang it, you're right, it doesn't work for definite integrals.  Well, this is why I keep it humble and tentative when I question experts.

Comment: @belisarius If the domain of integration is fixed throughout the problem, Jerry could probably do the algebra with indefinite integrals.  They seem to work better.

Comment: @belisarius One might add such a construct `h=Distribute[Integrate[g, x]] /. 
  Integrate[k_, x] -> 
   HoldForm[Integrate[k, {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]] // ReleaseHold ` and it will enable one to work with definite integrals. But the question is WHY it does not work for definite integrals plainly?