# Factoring a separable integral with a product of independent integrands

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic

I would like to input

```
someFunction[Integrate[p[x] p[y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]]
```

and to get the following output

```
(Integrate[p[x], {x, -1, 1}])^2
```

Is this possible? (Function p is undefined, I am interested in a symbolic expression only.)

UPD: **The question is not that how to define *someFunction* for this particular case. I am interested in a method which will work for any multiple integral: if there is a product function inside such integral then the answer has to be factorized as well.**

Best wishes,

Dmitri.

Comment: For searching purposes: what OP is dealing with is also called a *separable integral*.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Answer (score 9):

This will work with any number of independent integrants. Define:

```
repl[l_] := # /. Thread[#[[All, 1]] -> Table[x, {Length[#]}]] &[l]

inTfaC[int_] := Times @@ MapThread[Integrate[#1, #2] &, 
   repl /@ {First[#], Rest[#]} &[
    int /. {Integrate -> List, Times -> List}]]
```

Now verify:

```
test = Integrate[p[x] p[y] q[z] r[s] r[u], 
{x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, a, 2}, {s, 3, b}, {u, 3, b}]
```

[image]

```
inTfaC[test]
```

[image]

Comment: Probably, I was not exact. I do not want to teach Mathematica how to factorize the answer. I would like to ask it to do this. The same should be done for a triple integral and so on,

Comment: @Dmitri updated

Comment: Great! Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Be very careful!  This will even factor integrals where the variables only "talk to each other" through the integrals' limits!  For example, try `inTfaC[Integrate[p[x] p[y], {x, -1, y}, {y, -1, 1}]]`.

Comment: @evanb Your integral does not satisfy the question title: "Factoring a **separable** integral with a product of **independent integrands** " - and I assume that OP deals with those only.

Comment: Ah, you're right.  Nevertheless, it's important to emphasize!

Comment: I would like only to mention, that @Vitaliy Kaurov method fails in the case then the integral is not multiple (i.e. just one integral). More difficult case is then we have to factorize if only it is possible; i.e. 
    inTfaC[Integrate[p[x,y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]]
will return the same expressions, whereas
    inTfaC[Integrate[p[x]p[y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]]
will be factorised.

Answer (score 2):

Adapting `linearExpand` from my answer to [How to do algebra on unevaluated integrals?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/64422/how-to-do-algebra-on-unsolved-integrals/64447#64447), we can come up with some transformations to factor separable multiple integrals.  The function `someFunction` internally deals with and returns [`Inactive`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inactive.html) integrals, which can be evaluated with [`Activate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Activate.html), if appropriate or desired.

**Examples**

```
someFunction[Integrate[p[x] p[y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
someFunction[Integrate[p[x] p[y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 100}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
someFunction[Integrate[p[x] p[y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, x}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
someFunction[Integrate[p[x] (p[y] + q[y]), {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]^2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
(* Vitaliy Kaurov's example *)
test = Integrate[p[x]*p[y]*q[z]*r[s]*r[u],
 {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, 0, 2}, {s, 3, 10}, {u, 3, 10}];
someFunction[test]
% /. changeVar[x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
someFunction[Integrate[q[x], {x, 0, 2}] + test]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Outline**

We need some auxilliary functions.

- **`iterated`** converts a multiple integral into an iterated integral.
- **`linearExpand`** applies linearity properties to an integral, distributing the integral over a sum and factoring out constants.
- **`factorConstants`** recursively factors constants out of nested integrals using `linearExpand`.
- **`changeVar`** changes the variable of integration.

These can be applied by `Simplify` via the [`TransformationFunctions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TransformationFunctions.html) option. The trick, and it can be tricky, is devising a [`ComplexityFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexityFunction.html) that will prefer a result in a factored out form.  Note that we use `changeVar` only to combine two integrals that are equivalent.  At the end we can change the variable in the independent integrals to the same one.

**Code dump**

```
ClearAll[linearExpand, iterated, factorConstants, changeVar, someFunction];

linearExpand[e_, x_, head_] := 
  e //. {op : head[arg_Plus, __] :> Distribute[op], 
    head[arg1_Times, var_, rest___] /; ! FreeQ[var, x] :> 
     With[{dependencies = Internal`DependsOnQ[#, x] & /@ List @@ arg1}, 
      Pick[arg1, dependencies, False] *
       head[Pick[arg1, dependencies, True], var, rest]]};

iterated[Integrate[f_, dom : {_Symbol, _, _} ..]] := 
  Fold[Inactive[Integrate], f, Reverse@{dom}];
iterated[Inactive[Integrate][f_, dom : {_Symbol, _, _} ..]] := 
  Fold[Inactive[Integrate], f, Reverse@{dom}];

factorConstants[Inactive[Integrate][f_, {v_Symbol, a_, b_}]] := 
  Inactive[Integrate][
    f /. j : Inactive[Integrate][_, _] :> factorConstants[j], {v, a, b}] /.
      i : Inactive[Integrate][_, {v, _, _}] :> 
    linearExpand[i, v, Inactive[Integrate]];
factorConstants[x_] := x;

changeVar[Inactive[Integrate][f_, {v_, a_, b_}]] := 
  i : Inactive[Integrate][g_, {w_, a, b}] /; 
    Simplify[f == g /. v -> w] :> (i /. w -> v);
changeVar[v_] := 
  i : Inactive[Integrate][g_, {w_Symbol, _, _}] :> (i /. w /; FreeQ[g, Integrate] -> v);

someFunction[integral_] := 
  With[{v = 
     FirstCase[Hold[integral], 
      HoldPattern[(Integrate | Inactive[Integrate])[_, {x_, _, _}, ___]] :> x,
      Missing[], 
      Infinity]},
   (Simplify[
      integral /.
       {i : (Integrate | Inactive[Integrate])[_, {_Symbol, _, _}, {_Symbol, _, _} ..] :> 
          iterated@Inactivate[i, Integrate],
        i : (Integrate | Inactive[Integrate])[_, {_Symbol, _, _}] :>
          Inactivate[i, Integrate]},
      TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic,
        # /. i : Inactive[Integrate][f_, {_, _, _}] :> factorConstants[i] &,
        # /. changeVar /@ 
           DeleteDuplicates@
            Cases[#, Inactive[Integrate][f_, {v_, a_, b_}], Infinity] &},
      ComplexityFunction -> (LeafCount[#] +
          10 Count[{#}, 
            Inactive[Integrate][Inactive[Integrate][__], __], Infinity] +
          5 Count[{#}, 
            Inactive[Integrate][f_, __] /; ! FreeQ[f, Integrate], Infinity] -
          Count[{#}, Power[Inactive[Integrate][f_, __], _], Infinity] +
          Length@DeleteDuplicates@
            Cases[{#}, Inactive[Integrate][f_, {x_, _, _}] :> x, Infinity] &)
    ] /. changeVar[v]) /; FreeQ[v, Missing]
   ];
someFunction[expr_] := expr;
```

The first two terms after `LeafCount` of the `ComplexityFunction` penalize nested integrals, the first one penalizing nested integrals in which the constants have not been factored out.  The next term, being subtracted, rewards gathering powers of integrals.  The last term penalizes extra variables of integration, which drives `Simplify` to prefer changing variables to the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe for this case use:

```
someFunction[int_] := (int /. _[y] :> 1/2)^2
```