# Patterns with inactive integrals

Tags: pattern-matching

I am trying to do algebra on unsolved integrals but not getting the pattern-matching right. I want the correlation of f[x] and f[x]+a*d[x], normalized by their self correlations.

```
crInt[f_, g_, x_] := Inactive[Integrate][Expand[f[x]*g[x]], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}];
defInt[f_, x_] := Inactive[Integrate][f[x], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}];
corr[f_, g_, x_] := crInt[f, g, x] - defInt[f, x]*defInt[g, x];
h1 = corr[f, g, x]/Sqrt[corr[f, f, x]*corr[g, g, x]];
h2 = h1 /. g[x] -> f[x] + a*d[x];
h3 = h2 /. Integrate[q_, {v_, s__}] :> Distribute@Integrate[Expand[q], {v, s}];
h4 = h3 /. Integrate[q1___ r__ q2___, {v_, s__}] /; FreeQ[{r}, v] :> r Integrate[q1 q2, {v, s}]
```

The Expand/Distribute in the h3 line isn't Expanding the integrand, so the Distribute can't work.

In the h4 line, I'm trying to move any constants outside the integral, but I'm not sure I understand the difference between /. and //.

This Question builds on the discussion from my earlier question:
[How to do algebra on unevaluated integrals?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/64422/how-to-do-algebra-on-unsolved-integrals)

Comment: A couple of comments: `Distribute` won't work, because it has the wrong form (check the documentation). Second: I think to match `Integrate`, you need to actually put `Inactive[Integrate]`. Third: It seems like your definitions of the correlation functions and such are creating things like `dx^2`, which I don't understand. Edit: nope, nevermind, I misinterpreted the `^2` that was attached to the entire integral.

Answer (score 4):

```
crInt[f_, g_, x_] := Inactive[Integrate][Expand[f[x]*g[x]], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}];
defInt[f_, x_] := Inactive[Integrate][f[x], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}];
corr[f_, g_, x_] := crInt[f, g, x] - defInt[f, x]*defInt[g, x];
```

Then, define

```
rule0 = Inactive[Integrate][q_, {v_, s__}] :> Inactive[Integrate][Expand@q, {v, s}];
rule1 = Inactive[Integrate][HoldPattern[Plus[q__]], {v_, s__}] :> (Inactive[Integrate][#, {v, s}] & /@ q);
rule2 = Inactive[Integrate][q1___ r__ q2___, {v_, s__}] /; FreeQ[{r}, v] :> r Inactive[Integrate][q1 q2, {v, s}];
```

Finally, do

```
h1 = corr[f, g, x]/Sqrt[corr[f, f, x]*corr[g, g, x]];
h2 = h1 /. g[x] -> f[x] + a*d[x];
h3 = h2 /. rule0;
h4 = h3 /. rule1;
h5 = h4 /. rule2 // Expand;
```

A couple of things:

- You need to match `Inactive[Integrate]` rather than `Integrate`.
- `Distribute` doesn't work: it would only work if the syntax is `Integrate[Plus[a, b, c]]` rather than `Integrate[Plus[a,b,c], {x, d, e}]` (see the documentation). I replaced that with an explicit pattern matching replacement rule, but...
- ...`HoldPattern[Plus[q__]]` is necessary because, as pointed out by `Michael E2` in a comment below, `Plus` always evaluates, even if the argument is a pattern. So `Plus[q__]` evaluates to `q__` on the left-hand side of the replacement rule, which means the pattern will match any argument, rather than ones that have `Plus` as a `Head`.

As for `/.` vs. `//.`, the *best* I can say is to experiment; but a couple more notes:

- `/.` is `ReplaceAll`. It scans through an expression once, so `a + b /. {a -> b, b -> c, c -> d}` evaluates to `b + c`, where `a` has been replaced by `b` and `b` has been replaced by `a`, but no further replacements occur.
- `//.` is `ReplaceRepeated`. It does what `/.` does, except that it will repeat the procedure over and over again until it can no longer match any of the patterns on the LHS's of the replacement rules. So `a + b /. {a -> b, b -> c, c -> d}` evaluates to `2 d`

(Use `Trace` to see the process.)

Comment: Re `HoldPattern[Plus[q__]]` -- you're right on track about `Plus` evaluating.  The LHS  of a `Rule`/`RuleDelayed` evaluates unless wrapped in `HoldPattern`.  `Plus[x]`, whatever expression `x` happens to be, evaluates to (the value of) `x`.  So `[Plus[q__]] :> replacement` is the same as `q__ :> replacement`.

Comment: @MichaelE2. Thanks for that! It's something that's been bugging me or a long time.

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 3):

You can apply `IgnoringInactive` to the left hand side of the replacement rule to match without explicitly checking for `Inactive`.

Lines `h3` and `h4` would be

```
h3 = h2 /. 
   IgnoringInactive@Integrate[q_, {v_, s__}] :> 
    Distribute@Integrate[Expand[q], {v, s}];
h4 = h3 /. 
  IgnoringInactive[
    Integrate[q1___ r__ q2___, {v_, s__}]] /; FreeQ[{r}, v] :> 
   r Integrate[q1 q2, {v, s}]
```

and the distribution would occur.

Hope this helps.