# Solving linear equation with integrals

Tags: equation-solving, linear-algebra, integral-equations

I have a simple equation with respect to constants `A` and `B`, unfourtunately it's written using definite integrals with unknown functions in them which are to be calculated afterwards. Mathematica is trying to process those integrals and refuses to simply solve linear equation. Is there a way to tell the system not to deal with integrals but rather consider them constant expressions?

Example:

```
rhs = Integrate[Plus[Times[A, x[t]], Times[B, y[t]]], List[t, 0, 1]]
Solve[rhs == A, A]
```

This can't be solved.

But this can:

```
Solve[A x[t] + B y[t] == A, A]
```

However those equaitons are equally simple. How do I tell mathematica to work with integrals properly and express solution in terms of those?

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/64447/4999.  Note that the linearity properties of integrals cannot be properly applied unless the resulting integrals are known to be convergent. Since `A`, `B`, `x[t]`, and `y[t]` are unknown expressions, the integral should not be automatically decomposed. Some sort of manual intervention is going to be necessary, I think.

Comment: @MichaelE2 constants can be pulled out regardless of integral convergence. Is there a way to do so automatically? There is another problem - when integrals are quite bulky, mathematica spends a lot of time trying to evaluate before spitting them out in unchanged form. Is there away to prevent that?

Comment: You'd have to tell *M* that `A` and `B` are in fact constants.  (One could make an assignment `A = Exp[t]`, for instance.)  However, the built-in routines for manipulating `Integrate` seem to ignore the attribute `Constant`.  Algebraic manipulate of `Integrate` and `Sum` seem underdeveloped, compared to the rest of *M*.

Comment: As for *M* evaluating and reevaluating, the trick I used in my linked answer was to `Inactivate` the `Integrate`.  Pre V-10, one can use `Hold[Integrate]` or `HoldForm[Integrate]`.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to implement a linear operator that automatically expands itself:

```
ClearAll[int];
int[sum_Plus, d_] := int[#, d] & /@ sum;
int[Times[c_, e__], d : {x_, a_, b_}] /; Dt[c, x] == 0 := c int[Times[e], d];

ClearAll[A, B];
SetAttributes[A, Constant];
SetAttributes[B, Constant];
Solve[rhs == A /. Integrate -> int, A] /. int :> Integrate
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you don't want to use `Constant`, you could live slightly more dangerously and use [`D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/D.html) instead of [`Dt`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dt.html):

```
ClearAll[int];
int[sum_Plus, d_] := int[#, d] & /@ sum;
int[Times[c_, e__], d : {x_, a_, b_}] /; D[c, x] == 0 := c int[Times[e], d];

ClearAll[A, B];
Solve[rhs == A /. Integrate -> int, A] /. int :> Integrate
```

This also works without `int`, but only on indefinite integrals:

```
rhs = Integrate[Plus[Times[A, x[t]], Times[B, y[t]]], t];
Solve[Distribute[rhs] == A, A]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

***Combining like integrals***

```
rhs = Integrate[
  Plus[Times[2, Derivative[1][x][t],  
    Plus[Derivative[1][\[Phi]][t], Times[A, Derivative[2][x][t]]]], 
   Times[2, Derivative[1][y][t], 
    Plus[Derivative[1][\[Gamma]][t], Times[A, Derivative[2][y][t]]]]],
   List[t, 0, 1]];

intcombine = # /. 
    Plus[c_. Inactive[Integrate][a_, d_], 
      c_. Inactive[Integrate][b_, d_], rest___] :> 
     Plus[c*Inactive[Integrate][a + b, d], rest] &;

Solve[ExpandAll@rhs == A /. Integrate -> int, A] /. int :> Inactive[Integrate]
Simplify[%, TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, intcombine}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: For some reason, the first approach doesn't work with `rhs=Integrate[Plus[Times[2, Derivative[1][x][t], \
Plus[Derivative[1][\\[Phi]][t], Times[A, Derivative[2][x][t]]]], \
Times[2, Derivative[1][y][t], Plus[Derivative[1][\\[Gamma]][t], \
Times[A, Derivative[2][y][t]]]]], List[t, 0, 1]]`

Comment: Try `Solve[ExpandAll@rhs == A /. Integrate -> int, A] /. int :> Inactive[Integrate]`.  For `int` to work, the integrand must be in the form of a linear combination.  One could perhaps modify `int` to handle the expansion when all else fails.

Comment: That works almost perfectly. After integral is split into a lot of summands (more than necessary to pick A out), is there a way to gather them back?

Comment: @VsevolodA. Do you mean you want just one integral in (each of) the numerator and denominator of this?: http://i.stack.imgur.com/FKovN.png

Comment: Yes, to combine integrals wich have the same intervals.

Comment: @VsevolodA. Gotta run.  If the updated answer doesn't address the issue, or suggest a solution to you, let me know.  I'll probably be back in a few hours or so.