# Tell MMA that $\int_0^1 \alpha \beta(x) dx= \alpha \int_0^1 \beta(x) dx$

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Why is it that MMA excludes `alpha` from the integral in the first case but not in the second?

```
Integrate[alpha*beta[x],x] 
(* alpha Integrate[beta[x], x] *)

Integrate[alpha*beta[x], {x, 0, 1}]
(* Integrate[alpha*beta[x], {x, 0, 1}] *)
```

and how to have `Integrate[alpha*beta[x], {x, 0, 1}]` return `alpha*Integrate[beta[x], {x, 0, 1}]`?

Comment: Related/duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/64422/how-to-do-algebra-on-unevaluated-integrals