# Why doesn't Mathematica cancel this constant out of the integral?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, simplifying-expressions

I have the mathematical expression

```
Integrate[f[r], {r, τ, t}] == a*Integrate[f[r]/a, {r, τ, t}]
```

which is obviously true for all functions `f[r]` if a is a constant. However, Mathematica does not simplify the above expression to "true". Even `Simplify` and `FullSimplify` don't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's only true, if `Integrate[f[r], {r, \[tau], t}]` exists, but Mathematica doesn't know about the unknown function `f[r]`! Substitute `f ` by `Sin` for example and you  get `True` as expected.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann You're right. Is there a way to tell Mathematica that the integral exists for all upper and lower bounds for the general function `f`?

Comment: Sorry no idea. Surprisingly `Simplify[Integrate[f[r], r] == a*Integrate[f[r]/a, r]  , 
 Assumptions -> a > 0]` works!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Maybe thats because it's not defined for `a == 0`...

Comment: `a==0` is excluded by the assumptions!

Comment: `Simplify[Integrate[f[r], r] == a*Integrate[f[r]/a, r], 
 Assumptions -> a != 0]` does the job.

Comment: @user64494 That doesn't work for me...

Comment: @UlrichNeumann That actually doesn't work for me either

Comment: In the case of indefinite integrals, the cancellation appears to work even without `Simplify` (in MA 12.0.0.0)

Comment: @Hausdorff: Think of the case $a=0$.

Comment: @user64494 It does not matter in this case, since the result does not depend on the value of `a` (the limit $a\rightarrow 0$ is defined). `Integrate[f[r], r] == a*Integrate[f[r]/a, r]` yields `True` for me

Comment: @Hausdorff: Thank you for your personal opinion. However, I was taught division by zero is impossible. I think the answer is generic.

Comment: @user64494 Execute `x/x`.

Comment: In V12.1.1, `a*Integrate[f[r]/a, r]` evaluates to `Integrate[f[r], r]`

Comment: @Michel E2: That was discussed some time ago. I have no time to find a reference.

Comment: Is there a way to get this working in MA 8?

Comment: @HerpDerpington Try [`linearExpand[
 a Inactive[Integrate][f[r]/a, 
   r]]`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/64447/4999)

Comment: @usr64494 Yes, it was, so I'm surprised you're bringing it up. You still haven't learned how *Mathematica* works. You might also extend your knowledge of the [mathematics of rational functions](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/rational+function)

Comment: Michael E2: I was taught traditional math where the domains are taken into account.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Unfortunately that method does not work in MA 8, since `Inactivate` only exists from MA 10 onward.

Comment: Remove the Inactive? Change to plain Integrate. That might work. You can also replace Inactive with Hold or HoldForm (expr /. Integrate -> HoldForm[Integrate]). You have to do that in the code of

Comment: @MichaelE2 That works!

Comment: Feel free to post your solution! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mathematica does not like to take things out of integrals.

You can define the following rule:

```
repl = Integrate[x_ y__, {var_, bounds__}] /; FreeQ[x, var] :> 
  x Integrate[y, {var, bounds}];
```

And then Mathematica will happily factor out the "constants"

```
Integrate[f[r], {r, τ, t}] == 
  a*Integrate[f[r]/a, {r, τ, t}] /. repl
(* True *)
```

Comment: That breaks in this case for me: `(f[t] * Integrate[g[r], {r, a, t}] == Integrate[f[t]*g[r], {r, a, t}]) /. repl` evaluates the RHS integral without integrating. (But it does cancel constants...)

Comment: @HerpDerpington Your example works for me (MA 12.0.0.0)

Comment: @Hausdorff I have MA 8.0.0.0