# How can I teach Mathematica to break divergent integrals into terms?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, simplifying-expressions

For instance, I get the following expression:

$\int_0^{\infty } \left(\frac{e^2 x}{e^{2 x+2}-e^{2 x}}-\frac{x}{e^{2 x+2}-e^{2 x}}-\frac{e^2}{2 \left(e^{2 x+2}-e^{2 x}\right)}+\frac{3}{2 \left(e^{2 x+2}-e^{2 x}\right)}+\frac{1}{2}\right) \, dx+\frac{1}{2-2 e^2}$

I want it to be automatically simplified to $\int_0^\infty \frac12 dx$, because all other terms cancel each other (can be verified).

Or $\int_0^{\infty } \left(\frac{3 e^2 x^2}{6 e^x-12 e^{x+1}+6 e^{x+2}}-\frac{6 e x^2}{6 e^x-12 e^{x+1}+6 e^{x+2}}+\frac{3 x^2}{6 e^x-12 e^{x+1}+6 e^{x+2}}-\frac{9 e^2 x}{6 e^x-12 e^{x+1}+6 e^{x+2}}+\frac{24 e x}{6 e^x-12 e^{x+1}+6 e^{x+2}}-\frac{15 x}{6 e^x-12 e^{x+1}+6 e^{x+2}}+x+\frac{e^2}{6 e^x-12 e^{x+1}+6 e^{x+2}}-\frac{8 e}{6 e^x-12 e^{x+1}+6 e^{x+2}}+\frac{13}{6 e^x-12 e^{x+1}+6 e^{x+2}}\right) \, dx+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{1-2 e+e^2}$

should be simplified to $\int_0^\infty x dx$.

Or $\frac{12 e^4 \int_0^{\infty } \left(2 e^{-2 x} x+2 x+\frac{2}{e^{2 x+2}-e^{2 x}}-\frac{e^2}{e^{4 x}+e^{4 x+2}}+\frac{1}{e^{4 x}+e^{4 x+2}}+1\right) \, dx}{12 e^4-12}-\frac{12 \int_0^{\infty } \left(2 e^{-2 x} x+2 x+\frac{2}{e^{2 x+2}-e^{2 x}}-\frac{e^2}{e^{4 x}+e^{4 x+2}}+\frac{1}{e^{4 x}+e^{4 x+2}}+1\right) \, dx}{12 e^4-12}-\frac{e^4}{12 e^4-12}-\frac{18 e^2}{12 e^4-12}-\frac{5}{12 e^4-12}$

should be simplified to $\frac16+2\int_0^\infty x dx+\int_0^\infty 1 dx$.

Is there a way to make Mathematica doing so?

P.S. Input form for the first example:

```
1/(2 - 2*E^2) + 
 Integrate[
  1/2 + 3/(2*(-E^(2*x) + E^(2 + 2*x))) - 
   E^2/(2*(-E^(2*x) + E^(2 + 2*x))) - 
       x/(-E^(2*x) + E^(2 + 2*x)) + (E^2*x)/(-E^(2*x) + 
      E^(2 + 2*x)), {x, 0, Infinity}]
```

For the second example:

```
-(1/3) + 1/(1 - 2*E + E^2) + 
 Integrate[(13*E^x)/(6 - 12*E + 6*E^2) - (8*E^(1 + x))/(6 - 12*E + 
      6*E^2) + 
       E^(2 + x)/(6 - 12*E + 6*E^2) - 
   x + (15*E^x*x)/(6 - 12*E + 6*E^2) - (24*E^(1 + x)*x)/(6 - 12*E + 
      6*E^2) + 
       (9*E^(2 + x)*x)/(6 - 12*E + 6*E^2) + (3*E^x*x^2)/(6 - 12*E + 
      6*E^2) - 
       (6*E^(1 + x)*x^2)/(6 - 12*E + 6*E^2) + (3*E^(2 + x)*x^2)/(6 - 
      12*E + 6*E^2), {x, 0, Infinity}]
```

For the third example:

```
-(5/(-12 + 12*E^4)) - (18*E^2)/(-12 + 12*E^4) - E^4/(-12 + 12*E^4) - 
   (12*Integrate[
     1 + 2/(-E^(2*x) + E^(2 + 2*x)) + 1/(E^(4*x) + E^(2 + 4*x)) - 
      E^2/(E^(4*x) + E^(2 + 4*x)) + 
            2*x + (2*x)/E^(2*x), {x, 0, Infinity}])/(-12 + 12*E^4) + 
   (12*E^4*
    Integrate[
     1 + 2/(-E^(2*x) + E^(2 + 2*x)) + 1/(E^(4*x) + E^(2 + 4*x)) - 
      E^2/(E^(4*x) + E^(2 + 4*x)) + 
            2*x + (2*x)/E^(2*x), {x, 0, Infinity}])/(-12 + 12*E^4)
```

Full code example:

```
f[x_] := 1 + Exp[-2 x]
g[x_] := 1

omb := D[Sum[
   Refine[DifferenceDelta[Integrate[Integrate[f[t], {t, 0, y}], y], 
      y]*DifferenceDelta[Integrate[Integrate[g[t], {t, 0, y}], y], y],
     y > 0], {y, 0, x - 1}], x]
Func := D[omb, x]; Const := omb /. x -> 0
Inactivate[
    Integrate[f[x], {x, 0, Infinity}]\[CenterDot]Integrate[
      g[x], {x, 0, Infinity}], Integrate] == 
   FullSimplify[Const + Integrate[Func, {x, 0, Infinity}]] // 
  ExpandAll // Quiet
```

Comment: Please include the corresponding Mathematica code in copy and paste form (`InputForm`)

Comment: @BobHanlon I do not understand, what should I include.

Comment: Why not acting with FullSimplify on the integrand? Are there some surface terms leftover?

Comment: At a minimum, the Mathematica code for the integrands. You could also include the integrals with `Inactive[Integrate]`

Comment: @FilipeMiguel the terms under integral cancel with terms outside integral.

Comment: @BobHanlon added.

Comment: The code for the second example does not seem to match the TeX.

Answer (score 5):

You might use `Distribute[Integrate[Expand[f], {x, 0, Infinity}]]`, but it seems easier to distribute with `Map`:

```
Check[ (* omit Check if not desired *)
 res = 1/(2 - 2*E^2) + 
    Integrate[
     1/2 + 3/(2*(-E^(2*x) + E^(2 + 2*x))) - 
      E^2/(2*(-E^(2*x) + E^(2 + 2*x))) - 
      x/(-E^(2*x) + E^(2 + 2*x)) + (E^2*x)/(-E^(2*x) + 
         E^(2 + 2*x)), {x, 0, Infinity}],
  (** Here's where we distribute Integrate: **)
  res /. 
   HoldPattern[Integrate[f_, x__]] :> With[{terms = Expand[f]},
     Integrate[#, x] & /@ terms /; MatchQ[terms, _Plus]],
  (**                                       **)
  Integrate::idiv] // Simplify

(* Integrate[1/2, {x, 0, Infinity}] *)
```

---

*Update:*

One needs the full linearity of integrals to deal with the OP's problem, and `Integrate` does not do that.  Using [`linearExpand`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/64447/4999) from another answer we get:

```
Clear[linearExpand];
linearExpand[e_] := 
  e //. {int : Inactive[Integrate][_Plus, _] :> Distribute[int], 
    Inactive[Integrate][integrand_Times, dom : {x_, _, _} | x_] :> 
     With[{dependencies = 
        Internal`DependsOnQ[#, x] & /@ List @@ integrand}, 
      Pick[integrand, dependencies, False]*
       Inactive[Integrate][Pick[integrand, dependencies, True], dom]]};

linearExpand[Inactive[Integrate][Func // Expand, {x, 0, Infinity}]] //
   Activate // Simplify

(*
  1/(2*(-1 + E^2)) +
   (1/2)*Integrate[1, {x, 0, Infinity}] + 
   2*Integrate[x, {x, 0, Infinity}]
*)
```

Comment: Ah, this seems to work (I didn't trust `Distribute` not to evaluate `Integrate` before distributing, and maybe I still shouldn't?): `res /. HoldPattern[i : Integrate[f_, x__]] :> With[{terms = Expand[f]}, Distribute[Unevaluated@Integrate[terms, x]] /; MatchQ[terms, _Plus]]`

Comment: Distribute by itself works fine with the result but does not work in the code.

Comment: @Anixx I don't know what you mean by "does not work in the code" since it gives me the same result that you said was desired in the OP (except the second example, in which the code is different than the TeX).  I guess I'm not sure what "`Distribute` by itself" means, since I can imagine it being applied correctly or incorrectly.

Comment: The following code gives the desired answer:`FullSimplify[5/(12 - 12*E^2) + E^2/(12 - 12*E^2) + Distribute[Integrate[1/2 + 3/(2*(-E^(2*x) + E^(2 + 2*x))) - E^2/(2*(-E^(2*x) + E^(2 + 2*x))) + 2*x - x/(-E^(2*x) + E^(2 + 2*x)) + (E^2*x)/(-E^(2*x) + E^(2 + 2*x)), {x, 0, Infinity}]]]` The problem happens when the integrand is a variable. Inserting "Evaluate" does not help.

Comment: This seems to work the way I thought you wanted: `Distribute[Integrate[x, {x, 0, Infinity}]]`. (`Distribute` actually does nothing when the integrand is a variable, since the `Head` of the integrand is not `Plus`.)

Comment: I wonder, how can I modify the code so that it to work with integrand being a variable... I want the same result. Can I apply distribute to the second level?...

Comment: @Anixx Forgive me, but I guess I'm just slow. If the integrand is just a variable, then isn't the integral exactly this: `Integrate[x, {x, 0, Infinity}]`? And shouldn't it just remain as is in that case, since it is divergent?

Comment: I meant expression variable. The code is as follows: `FullSimplify[Const + Integrate[Func, {x, 0, Infinity}]]` and before that, `Func := D[omb, x];`. If I add distribute before the Integrate, it does not work.

Comment: @Anixx Without a complete working example, I probably cannot help further. `Func` and its integral evaluate to `0` for me, so there's no problem. I assume that's because `omb` is not just the symbol `omb` , but defined to be some else. There seems to be layer after layer followed by yet another unmentioned layer and we've still not arrived at a problem on which Distribute doesn't work.

Comment: I've added the full code example.

Comment: The desired result of the code listed at the end of the OP is $\int_0^{\infty } \frac{1}{2} \, dx+\int_0^{\infty } 2 x \, dx-\frac{1}{12}$

Comment: @Anixx See my update.  I didn't get `1/12`.  Maybe you could check.

Comment: In my code the Const term is added.

Comment: Your code is sooo complicated. Is there a way to simply make Distribute to work with an expression encoded in variable?

Comment: @A Distribute works on expressions of the form `f[x1, x2,..]` when the head of any of the `x1`, `x2` etc. is `Plus`.  In `Distribute[variable]`, `variable` is evaluated first, and then `Distribute` is evaluated. `Distribute` will work if the expression to which `variable` evaluates is of the appropriate form.  So `Distribute` always works with an expression encoded in variable; if it seems to fail, it is because of the expression, not because of the variable. (E.g., to get the expression in the appropriate form with the head of an argument to be `Plus`, one might need `Expand` or `ExpandAll`.)

Comment: Okay, so I made Distribute to sort-of work, but still no simplification and the integrals not cancelled: `-(1/12)+(1/2)Integrate[1,{x,0,∞}]+
Integrate[(11x)/(3-3E^2),{x,0,∞}]+
Integrate[(5E^2x)/(3-3E^2),{x,0,∞}]+
Integrate[(5x)/(3E^2-3),{x,0,∞}]+
Integrate[(11E^2x)/(3E^2-3),{x,0,∞}]+
Integrate[-((5x^2)/(E^2-1)),{x,0,∞}]+
Integrate[(5x^2)/(E^2-1),{x,0,∞}]+
Integrate[-((5E^2x^2)/(E^2-1)),{x,0,∞}]+
Integrate[(5E^2x^2)/(E^2-1),{x,0,∞}]+
Integrate[(4x^3)/(3-3E^2),{x,0,∞}]+
Integrate[(4E^2x^3)/(3-3E^2),{x,0,∞}]+
Integrate[(4x^3)/(3E^2-3),{x,0,∞}]+
Integrate[(4E^2x^3)/(3E^2-3),{x,0,∞}]`

Comment: When applied to the final answer, Distribute cancels all.

Comment: Oh, well, finally this worked: added FullSimplify inside Expand: `FullSimplify[Const + Distribute[Integrate[ExpandAll[FullSimplify[Func]], {x, 0, Infinity}]]] //ExpandAll // Quiet`

Comment: All works, so I added my own answer. It is definitely based on your advice and hints, although the solution is different (and I think, simpler).

Answer (score 0):

The first example is fairly easy, the others need more work...

```
Clear["Global`*"]

conv = a_. + b_. * Inactive[Integrate][integrand_, iter_List] :> 
   Simplify[
    a + Simplify[
      b*Integrate[#, iter] & /@ (integrand // FullSimplify // Expand)]];

Off[Integrate::idiv]

1/(2 - 2*E^2) + 
  Inactive[Integrate][
   1/2 + 3/(2*(-E^(2*x) + E^(2 + 2*x))) - E^2/(2*(-E^(2*x) + E^(2 + 2*x))) - 
    x/(-E^(2*x) + E^(2 + 2*x)) + (E^2*x)/(-E^(2*x) + E^(2 + 2*x)), {x, 0, 
    Infinity}] /. conv
```

[image]

Although it is not clear what this integral tells you that the original didn't: the integral is divergent.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the trick was to use Distribute outside of Integrate and ExpandAll and FullSimplify inside:

```
FullSimplify[Const + Distribute[Integrate[ExpandAll[FullSimplify[Func]], 
{x, 0, Infinity}]]] // Quiet
```

The both `FullSimplify`s are needed here, as well as `ExpandAll` inside Integrate.

Full code:

```
f[x_] := 1 + Exp[-2 x]
g[x_] := 1

omb := D[Sum[
   Refine[DifferenceDelta[Integrate[Integrate[f[t], {t, 0, y}], y], 
      y]*DifferenceDelta[Integrate[Integrate[g[t], {t, 0, y}], y], y],
     y > 0], {y, 0, x - 1}], x]
Func := D[omb, x]; Const := omb /. x -> 0
Inactivate[
   Integrate[f[x], {x, 0, Infinity}]\[CenterDot]Integrate[
     g[x], {x, 0, Infinity}], Integrate] == 
  FullSimplify[
   Const + Distribute[
     Integrate[
      ExpandAll[FullSimplify[Func]], {x, 0, Infinity}]]] // Quiet
```

And the result:
$\int _0^{\infty }\left(1+e^{-2 x}\right)dx\cdot \int _0^{\infty }1dx=\int_0^{\infty } \frac{1}{2} \, dx+\int_0^{\infty } 2 x \, dx-\frac{1}{12}$