# How to integrate a symbolic sum?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, summation

I'm trying to integrate a function that involves a *finite* sum:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\sum_{j=1}^n (e^{-b t^2}r_j) \,dt$$

I think it should be possible to take the exponent *outside* the sum:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left(e^{-b t^2} \sum_{j=1}^n r_j \right)dt=\sum_{j=1}^n r_j \times \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-b t^2} dt$$

I write it in Mathematica like this:

```
$Assumptions=_\[Element]Reals
Assuming[
b>0,
Integrate[Sum[Exp[-b t^2]*r[j],{j,1,n}],{t,-\[Infinity],+\[Infinity]}]
]
```

This, however, simply returns the integral unchanged:

$$\int_{-\infty }^{\infty } \left(\sum _{j=1}^n e^{-b t^2} r(j)\right)\, dt$$

If I specify a number for $n$, I get the expected result:

$$\frac{\sqrt{\pi } (r(1)+r(2)+r(3)+r(4)+r(5))}{\sqrt{b}}$$

---

How do I extract $e^{-bt^2}$ outside the sum? Alternatively, how do I bring the integral inside the sum? More generally, how do I integrate this?

Comment: Why don't you move it outside yourself? ``Sum[r[j], {j, 1, n}]*Integrate[Exp[-b t^2], {t, -\[Infinity], +\[Infinity]}]``

Comment: @Domen, this is a simplified example. I actually have a bigger expression that'll get really long if I extract everything manually. I could probably integrate this by hand, but I was hoping that Mathematica can automate this for me.

Comment: `Simplify` and `FullSimplify` also can't bring a constant factor outside the sum: `FullSimplify[Sum[a*Indexed[r, j], {j, 1, n}]]` returns the sum of `a*r_j` (as opposed. to `a` times the sum of `r_j`), but specifying a number instead of `n` correctly produces `a*(r_1+r_2+...)`

Comment: I think the reason is that you can exchange sum and integrate if the sum is known to be finite.  See [when-can-a-sum-and-integral-be-interchanged](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83721/when-can-a-sum-and-integral-be-interchanged/83747) and here Mathematica does not know the sum is finite of not, because it does not know `r[j]` is finite.  For example, if you replace `r[j]` with just `j` then it works.  `ClearAll[b,n,j,r,t];
f[t_]:=Sum[Exp[-b t^2]*j,{j,1,n}];
Assuming[Element[b,Reals]&&b>0,Integrate[f[t],t]]` and gives `(n*(1 + n)*Sqrt[Pi]*Erf[Sqrt[b]*t])/(4*Sqrt[b])` ...

Comment: .. so if someone can figure how to tell Mathematica that the sum is `finite`  or `r[j]` is finite, then may be there will be a better chance to have it work.

Comment: @Nesser, I tried adding assumptions like `Indexed[r, j] > 0 && Indexed[r, j] < 1` to both the sum and the integral, but this didn't change anything. I also tried adding `n > 0 && n < 6` to these assumptions to indicate that the sum is finite, but this didn't help either...

Comment: This is a Mathematica limitation.  Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Using `linearExpand` from [How to do algebra on unevaluated integrals?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/64422/how-to-do-algebra-on-unsolved-integrals/64447#64447) :

```
Clear[linearExpand];
linearExpand[e_, x_, head_] := 
  e //. {op : head[arg_Plus, __] :> Distribute[op], 
    head[arg1_Times, rest__] :> 
     With[{dependencies = Internal`DependsOnQ[#, x] & /@ List @@ arg1}, 
      Pick[arg1, dependencies, False] head[
        Pick[arg1, dependencies, True], rest]]};

linearExpand[Sum[Exp[-b t^2]*r[j], {j, 1, n}], j, Sum]
```

[image]

```
Assuming[b > 0,
 Integrate[
  linearExpand[Sum[Exp[-b t^2]*r[j], {j, 1, n}], j, Sum],
  {t, -\[Infinity], +\[Infinity]}]
 ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use a replacement [`Rule`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rule.html) to swap the order when appropriate.

```
Clear["Global`*"]

swap = Integrate[Sum[f_, iter1_, opts1___], iter2_, opts2___] :> 
   Sum[Integrate[f, iter2, opts2], iter1, opts1];

expr[n_Integer?Positive] = Assuming[b > 0, (Integrate[
     Sum[Exp[-b t^2]*r[j], {j, 1, n}], {t, -∞, +∞}] /. swap)]

(* Sum[(Sqrt[Pi]*r[j])/Sqrt[b], {j, 1, n}] *)

expr[5] // Simplify

(* (Sqrt[π] (r[1] + r[2] + r[3] + r[4] + r[5]))/Sqrt[b] *)
```